# How to simulate the plugging and unplugging of an HDMI cable through software?

Tags: systemd, xorg, nvidia, suspend, hdmi

After some struggle, I got `systemctl suspend` working with my Nvidia graphics card; only that when machine resumes, the monitor is blank. Yet I discovered that if I unplug the HDMI cable and plug it in again, it recovers and the image is back.

Now I wonder if I could run a command that does the same as the manual unplugging? It seems that Linux is perfectly able to reset the state; but I don't know how to trigger it (through software).

**So, I'm looking for a command that resets the HDMI connection. Do you know if that is possible?**

One caveat is that in that situation, the screensaver will be active. That means, it would need to be a script that can be run on resume without any interaction from my side.

(How to fix the problem of the blank screen is a separate question. From what I see, I'm not the only one affected by it. Even getting even to the state where it doesn't freeze after waking up was a success for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In X11 `xset dpms force off ; xset dpms force on` might fix it.

In wayland, you might be able to do something with `swayidle` but I haven't tried it.